# Vue.js working with relationship database, and dealing with Full-Stack Web Apps?

Tags: sqlite, express, vue.js, vuejs2

I've been following this youtube tutorial, [working with Vue.js and Express.js](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3zw5LgKDMhg) (it uses sqlite as its database), and was wondering if someone can direct me to where I can look into relationship database?

I may be jumping the gun here, and I'm only on Part 5 of the tutorial, but I was just thinking if I can do some research or if someone can guide me to the right direction, I'd like to learn about what I need to do to deal with relationship databases.

I used to dabble in Ruby on Rails, and they had nested forms, and I'm trying to learn to do a Full Stack web app with Vue.js, but not sure what the equivalent to RoR's nested forms?

I see a lot of posts that people use Vue.js with Laravel? Is this the best way to go about building a full stack? Or should I relearn RoR and implement Vue.js into it?

Comment: You should work with the relational database at backend side. Eg: Just working with Rails and build your own APIs in the server side. Then all you need to do is you some http library to call these apis in VueJS. VueJS just an `client side` library and you should not working with database or something else on it

Comment: It doesn't matter what you use for the backend, the general process is to create an API then make calls to that API from your Vue app. You will find many people using Laravel because it ships with Vue, but it takes a bit of work to get it set up for use in an SPA. You will also find many people using `RoR`, `Python` and `C#` to build their backends, so go with what you are comfortable with.

Answer (score 0):

if you need build with complate js you can go with meteor.js with vue meteor https://github.com/meteor-vue/vue-meteor .

> Meteor is a full stack JavaScript (JS) framework, made up of a collection of libraries and packages, bound together. But some people call Meteor magic.
>   https://www.upwork.com/hiring/development/meteorjs-node-js-framework/
>   https://www.meteor.com/tutorials

Still meteor only officially release extension for react and angular. but vue-meteor have very positive feedback and you can try on that.

and as you mention , you can go thru with ROR backend and vue front end using vue CLI https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli.